# SPARQL optional not bound VS filter not exists

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

Is there a difference (in term of performances, respects of standards or anything else) between:

```
select distinct ?planeWithoutPassengers where {
    ?planeWithoutPassengers a <http://example.org/plane> .
    filter not exists {
        ?planeWithoutPassengers <http://example.org/hasPassenger> ?passenger .
    }
}
```

And:

```
select distinct ?planeWithoutPassengers where {
    ?planeWithoutPassengers a <http://example.org/plane> .
    optional {
        ?planeWithoutPassengers <http://example.org/hasPassenger> ?passenger .
    }
    filter (!bound(?passenger)).
}
```

Comment: No, the second one is the older version which also works on SPARQL 1.0 engines. And clearly, the first one is (at least for me) much more understandable with a more intuitive syntax

Comment: Yes there may be some performance difference but it's probably implementation and data dependent. As others have suggested use the first form because your intent is clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference. The second one is the older version which also works on SPARQL 1.0 engines. However the first one is preferred as it reads more intuitively.